# SQL many joins many to many

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, many-to-many

I have 5 tables:

Table Reports

```
Report_Id | Report_name
-----------------
      1     | Income
      2     | Outcomes
      3     | Costs
```

Many to many table ReportsIpRel

```
Ip_Id | Report_Id
-----------------
    6   |    1
    4   |    2
    5   |    2
    2   |    2
    1   |    3
```

Table of InfoProviders

```
Ip_Id | Ip_Name
-----------------
    6   |    Comission
    4   |    Comapny
    5   |    Others
    2   |    People
    1   |    Traveler
```

Many to many table QueriesIpRel

```
Ip_Id | Query_Id
-----------------
    6   |    3
    4   |    3
    5   |    3
    2   |    5
    1   |    1
```

And table of Queries

```
Query_Id | Query_Name
-----------------
    1   |    connection
    2   |    distantcon
    3   |    shortconn
    4   |    linking
    5   |    grounding
```

The SELECT I am trying to achieve is the following:

```
Report_Id | Report_name | Ip_Id | Ip_Name | Query_Id | Query_Name
    2     | Outcomes    |  4    | Comapny |  3       | shortconn
    2     | Outcomes    |  5    | Others  |  3       | shortconn
    2     | Outcomes    |  2    | People  |  5       | grounding
```

I tried many left/inner joins like this:

```
left outer join ReportsIPRel rir on r.Report_Id = rir.Report_Id
left outer join InfoProvider ipr on rir.Ip_Id = ipr.Ip_Id
left outer join QueriesIPRel qir on ipr.Ip_Id = qir.Ip_Id 
left outer join Queries q on qir.Query_Id = q.Query_Id
where r.Report_Id= '2'
```

but all for nothing.

I have to use where condition: WHERE report_Id = '2' /EXAMPLE

I'm trying to do this in ms SQL in SQL Server Management Studio.

Thank you in advance

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is typically used with MS SQL Server. Are you sure you're using MySQL?

Comment: Ok, I added joins

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts with sample data instead of (or in addition to) tables. Or create online fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this query its working for me in SQL server:

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bc11b20dfdb97bdb625021250a151acc)

```
select r.*, ipr.ip_id, ipr.Ip_Name, q.uery_Id, q.Query_Name from
reports r
left outer join ReportsIPRel rir on r.Report_Id = rir.Report_Id
left outer join InfoProviders ipr on rir.Ip_Id = ipr.Ip_Id
left outer join QueriesIPRel qir on ipr.Ip_Id = qir.Ip_Id 
left outer join Queries q on qir.Query_Id = q.uery_Id
where r.Report_Id= '2'
```